# RSpec and Factory for testing next, prev records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have a User model which has methods for a next and previous user:

```
def next_user
  User.where("id > ?", id).order("id ASC").first
end

def prev_user
  User.where("id < ?", id).order("id DESC").first
end
```

I'm trying to setup a test using RSpec and Factory girl to test this, and am not sure of the approach - i'm only getting started with TDD.

I'm trying this:

```
describe "previous_next" do
   let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
   let(:next_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

   it "should know the next user" do
     expect(user.next_user).to eq next_user
   end

   it "should know the previous user" do
     expect(next_user.prev_user).to eq user
   end
end
```

here is the error

```
1) User previous_next should know the next user
 Failure/Error: expect(user.next_user).to eq next_user

   expected: #<User id: 7624, name: "Example User", email: "sample9@email.com", created_at: "2013-01-13 04:31:19", updated_at: "2013-01-13 04:31:19", password_digest: "$2a$04$mbzI.yXYd9eSSfXbjChROewwvCHLFQI6qq5IUNzAKo9O...", remember_token: "KMSmiEeOr6f_Sgi8KJffIA", admin: false, plan_id: nil, password_reset_token: nil, password_reset_sent_at: nil, stripe_customer_token: nil>
        got: nil

   (compared using ==)
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:93:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

 2) User previous_next should know the previous user
    Failure/Error: expect(next_user.prev_user).to eq user

   expected: #<User id: 7626, name: "Example User", email: "sample11@email.com", created_at: "2013-01-13 04:31:19", updated_at: "2013-01-13 04:31:19", password_digest: "$2a$04$uzrKmsXmVY7jUdRtfnfhUe89Jgy1176zE2UxdH90imJR...", remember_token: "gl10QvxjSMZYQS3JIgbREg", admin: false, plan_id: nil, password_reset_token: nil, password_reset_sent_at: nil, stripe_customer_token: nil>
        got: nil

   (compared using ==)
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:97:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

If i'm creating the next_user record as an instance of the :user Factory, why is it evaulating to nil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `let` lazily evaluates, it doesn't create the records until you ask for them.

Use `let!` instead of `let`. That eagerly evaluates them and forces the records to be created before the test.

Comment: That worked!  Thanks!  Is this outlined in the docs?  I didn't see it 'https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md'

Comment: http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Let/ExampleGroupMethods#let%21-instance_method